Storcli64 add vd resources already in use
I just change old disk to a new disk.
storcli64 /c0/dall show all show
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model               Sp Type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8:14     29 UGood -  7.276 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST8000NM0055-1RM112 D  -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The disk seem good but when i want to add it to raid with
storcli64 /c0 add vd  type=r0 drives=8:14 AWB pdcache=off

it show error
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = resources already in use

There is no cache
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = No Virtual Drive has Preserved Cache Data.

